# How to creating wordpress blog with two databases

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, multiple-databases

I have three blogs, blog A,blog B, blog C.Blog A contains its related data, blog B contains its related data but blog C contains both blog A and blog B data,

now i want to combined blog A and blog B into blog C.
I have tried using Hyperdb and getting results with `Hyperdb` (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hyperdb/).

now i am asking is there any better solution for this. Thank in advance

Comment: Import content from A and B into C using WordPress native export/import feature.

Comment: @bunumber9:did you understand the question.. it is not just onetime import or export content. need to show posts and popular events from both sites in blog c

Comment: why down vote i didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if it's not a one-off operation, I suggest you try to achieve this on a higher level, not messing up with databases.

Try something like https://wordpress.org/plugins/feedwordpress/ or https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/autoblog/

Or, if you're fancy coding something up yourself - here's a nice tutorial: http://www.worldoweb.co.uk/2012/display-wordpress-posts-on-another-wp-blog